# laggy scrolling tableview with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added images to my tableView cells and it made it laggy. I am still new to objective c and I do not understand what is causing this or how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

`group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]` is simply a string in my database that is unique to each object. The code works, it is just really laggy when trying to scroll.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFObject *group = groups[indexPath.row];


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d users", (int) [group[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] count]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are so many tools out there that can help you with this.

At a base level, the issue is that you are running a long process on the main thread, which blocks the UI. Loading an image from a non-local URL is time consuming, and you should do this on a background thread, so the UI is not blocked.

Again, there are so many ways to do this, and I strongly suggest you do some research on async resource loading, but this is one thing you can do within the confines of your own example:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFObject *group = groups[indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ // go to a background thread to load the image and not interfere with the UI
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // synchronize back to the main thread to update the UI with your loaded image
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d users", (int) [group[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] count]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    return cell;
}
```

I would also recommend using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) as the [author](https://github.com/mattt/) has built a very good category on top of `UIImageView` that allows you to load an image from a web URL in the background automatically. Again, there are many schools of thought on this process, and this is just one idea. I would recommend reading [this](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/) for a full on tutorial on the topic.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: thanks! that works almost perfectly! I have one more question on it however, why is it that when I scroll to the bottom then scroll back to the top fast then certain images appear to change? How can I fix that?

Comment: This is an issue with caching, which is an entire other bag of worms altogether. Again, AFNetworking is your friend :)